# Accessing RadListBox Items in Code-Behind

Tags: vb.net, telerik, postback, code-behind, radlistbox

I have the following RadListBox:

```
   <telerik:RadListBox ID="AttachmentsRadListBox"  CheckBoxes ="true" runat="server" />
```

It is located in a RadWindow, therefore I am populating it through the following code which is only called when RadWidnow becomes visible:

```
AttachmentsRadListBox.DataSource = AttachDT
AttachmentsRadListBox.DataTextField = "DocumentPath"
AttachmentsRadListBox.DataValueField = "DocumentID"
AttachmentsRadListBox.DataBind()
For Each item As RadListBoxItem In AttachmentsRadListBox.Items
     item.Checked = True
Next
```

So far so good, the RadListBox is populated and all the items are checked.

Now, there is a Save button on the RadWindow when pressed before closing the window I am trying to read the checked items in the AttachmentsRadListBox (Since the user might have changed the status of the checked items). But every effort on reading the items has failed, for example on the Save button click I have the following:

```
Dim test As Integer = AttachmentsRadListBox.Items.Count  // THIS IS ZERO
For Each item As RadListBoxItem In AttachmentsRadListBox.Items  // THERE ARE NO ITEMS
   If Not item.Checked Then
        Dim DocumentIDToDelete As Integer = item.Value
   End If
Next
```

Why is that the last piece of code does not behave as I hope? The AttachmentsRadListBox is not being bounded again through the postback. The only time that it is bounded is when the RadWindow appears. Then the Save button on the RadWindow obviously creates a postback but I don't understand why AttachmentsRadListBox contains no item at that point.

Answer (score 1):

Since you create the AttachmentsRadListBox dynamically, do you recreate it on subsequent postbacks? It is, in the end, a server control, so you need to make sure it is recreated, because otherwise ASP will destroy it upon a subsequent postback.
To see how you can access controls in the ContentTemplate of a RadWindow you can also examine this article: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/window-controls-container.html.

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying but then I've been using ASP .Net a lot before started taking advantage of Telerik controls. I think there is something very different here (in Telerik). Okay, let say I am trying to apply your fix: Upon pressing Save there is a post back which means I lose the RadListBox that I created and user changed the status of its check-boxes. Yes, I can create the RadListBox upon a post back but how do I preserve the status of the check boxes. I think I might need to handle check status changed of the RadListBox somehow. But I don't know how.

Comment: If you create the control with the same ID in the Page_Init event the data (including the checkboxes states) should be populated from the ViewState because the IDs of the controls (listbox and checkboxes) should be the same, so ASP should be able to match them with the POST data.